# empirical distribution function of variables, with changing distribution (triangular array?)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Assume $X_{1,n},...,X_{n,n}$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables and that $X_{i, n}\sim G_n$ ($G_n$ is the exact, not the empirical distribution function),

morveover we have $G_n\to G$ as $n\to\infty$.

It means that the variables are independent and identically distributed with distribution function $G_n$ for fixed $n$, but when $n$ changes, say now we have $n+1$, the distribution fuction also changes and now we, again, have $X_{1,n},...,X_{n+1,n+1}$ i.i.d. but with exact distribution function $G_{n+1}\neq G_n$.

Is there any result / theorem for showing

$F_n^{X_{1,n},...,X_{n,n}} \to G$ (the empirical distribution function of $X_{1,n},...,X_{n,n}$ converges to the limiting distribution function $G$) ?

where $F_n^{X_{1,n},...,X_{n,n}}(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} I_{X_{i, n}\leq t}$

(Glivenko-Cantelli is for the case where $X_{1,n},...,X_{n,n} = X_{1},...,X_{n}$ are i.i.d. and their distribution function remains always the same, $G_n = G \quad \forall n$)

Comment: I think it would be helpful for you to edit this a little and make things more explicit. For instance, you should write $X_{i,n}$ to make your dependence on $n$ explicit, so $(X_{i,n})_{1\le i\le n}$ are iid with distribution function $G_n$. You should also write what you mean by the empirical distribution function - I'm assuming you mean $F_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf1_{(-\infty,X_{i,n}]}$.

Comment: Thank you, I hope my question is now more comprehensible.

Comment: Thanks. We assume each $G_n$ is continuous - do we assume the same for $G$? Is $G$ a distribution function? Also, in what sense are you hoping the empirical distribution function converges? This is a random object, so we could have almost sure convergence, or convergence in probability, etc.

Comment: any statement about convergence would be great. $G_n$ and $G$ are both continuous distribution functions